# Make iMacro Check Frame F=1-8 until it finds a working one

Tags: imacros

So I've spent a few hours googling and trying to find a solution, but I failed. And I need to do this in an ,iim iMacro script, not .js script.

I have this iMacro:

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 2
TAB T=1
REFRESH
WAIT SECONDS=10
FRAME F=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:follow
FRAME F=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:follow
FRAME F=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:follow
FRAME F=4
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:follow
FRAME F=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:follow
FRAME F=6
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:follow
FRAME F=7
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:follow
FRAME F=8
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:follow
WAIT SECONDS=3
```

Now, the problem is that the FRAME F=# is dynamic, and to make this code work fast I had to put the SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 2 as well, otherwise the iMacro gets stuck for 5 seconds on each FRAME, making the iMacro very slow...

Is there a way to do something like:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var letters = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']; var string = ''; for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){string += letters[parseInt(Math.random() * 25)]}; string")
```

And then use: FRAME F={{!VAR1}} in every place needed???

I basically need the code to start checking for Frames, and check 1, then 2, then 3, etc until it finds the working one, and the second it does to move on.

I'm using the iMacros addon for Firefox.

Thank you

Comment: Basically, my script above works, but I would like to make it a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why not to play the macro in loop mode? I.e. `FRAME F={{!LOOP}}` in order not to multiply lines.

Comment: I tried that already. I also tried ALL of the recording options the iMacros firefox addon offers. Nothing works for me except that code I shared above.

Comment: For testing purposes you might remove the `REFRESH` command and try to play the macro in loop mode ( `FRAME F={{!LOOP}}` ) setting the ‘Max:’ value to 8.